# UTM to lat/long conversion using arc length formulae from library

Tags: convert, utm

Most of the descriptions I have seen for converting Lat/Long into UTM have some method of estimating ellipse arc lengths mixed into the formulas (e.g. see http://www.linz.govt.nz/geodetic/conversion-coordinates/projection-conversions/transverse-mercator-preliminary-computations/index.aspx) .

I want to be able to use the arc length formulas provided by a separate library.  Can anyone point me to a description of Lat/Long -> UTM conversion which just treats the ellipse arc length formulas generically without specifying a particular estimation method?  I'm not clear on what is the GIS stuff and what is the ellipse stuff with these methods.

Comment: I'd use a library like PROJ.4, which is incorporated into OGR. There wouldn't be too many of us that project long-hand, rather we would use a library that converts points into a different spatial reference. What is it you're trying to do? What libraries do you have available? Also, an indication of what programming/scripting language you're using could also be helpful.

Comment: PROJ.4 appears to have its own implementation of ellipse arc length formulas.  But I want to use my ellipse arc length methods instead.